# Why do I cannot import variable from __init__.py?

Tags: python

There is folder with 2 documnet - `__init__.py` and `main.py`.

Code in `__init__.py`:

```
a = 1
```

Code in `main.py`:

```
from . import a

print(a)
```

When I try to run `main.py`, the terminal displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[myfolder]/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import a
ImportError: cannot import name 'a'
```

Comment: How exactly do you attempt to run main.py? What is the current working directory, and what command do you use?

Comment: I used `C:/Users/[myusername]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe [myfolder]/main.py` in PowerShell

Comment: What about `from myfolder import a`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I try, I instead get [a different issue that I completely expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py); and when I apply the answer shown there (which I was also completely familiar with) it works properly. Although maybe 3.6 reported the problem this way?